# How to write script to update symbolic link of libraries (multiple files)

Tags: bash, symlink

Would like to enquire on how to write symbolic links for multiple files? like writing a bash script

Basically the file is gstreamer library, the library is of such patterns. An example is as of below

```
libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so      should link to  libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0                                                                                                                    
libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0    should link to  libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1806.0                                                                                                                  
libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1404.0  (the old library)                                                                                                            
libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1806.0   (the new library)
```

I have attempted to do something like the following

```
ln -sf libgst*.0 libgst*
ln -sf libgst*.0.1806.0  libgst*.0
```

But it always failed saying libgst***.0.1806.0 is not a directory. where have I went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ln -sf libgst*.0 libgst*
```

expands (in your case) to

```
ln -sf libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0 libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1404.0 libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1806.0 libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0 libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1404.0 libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1806.0
```

because `libgst*.0` matches `libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0`, `libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1404.0`, and `libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1806.0`, while `libgst*` matches all four files.

With multiple arguments like these, `ln` expects the last one to be a directory; the purpose of this variant of `ln`, with *n* arguments where *n* > 2, is to create links to all the names files (non-option arguments 1 to *n*-1) in the given directory (argument *n*).

Assuming that you’re always *replacing* existing links, never creating new ones, your first command can be replaced by

```
ln -sf libgst*.so.0 libgst*.so
```

(but if those two links exist, the command is unnecessary).

Your second command should be replaced by

```
ldconfig
```

which will correctly update the links, and the library cache (which is what the dynamic linker really uses).

Comment: `ln -sf libgst*.0 libgst*.so` won't work either as `libgst*.0` matches the old *and* new lib and the `.so.0` link.

Comment: Yes, I’d fixed that in the meantime to `ln -sf libgst*.so.0 libgst*.so`.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand what the `*` expansion does: It replaces the word ith the `*` by all matching existing filenames, so `ln -sf libgst*.0 libgst*` would be turned into

```
ln -sf libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1404.0 libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1806.0 libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1404.0 libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1806.0
       ´----------------------------------v----------------------------------´ `----------------------------------v----------------------------------´
                                  matching libgst*.0                                                      matching libgst*
```

In your case, both globs are expanded to the same two file (or additionally to matching symlinks that do already exist), so you have for filenames to the `ln` command. In this case `ln` expects the last name to be a directory, where all symlinks should be placed. That's why you get this error message.

But you need something different: The classical form `ln -s file symlink`, creating one link at a time. If you don't want to write it separately, you need to loop, if there is a logic for it like

```
for file in libgst*1806.0; do ln -sf "$file" "${file%.1806.0}; done
```